# No se muestra la pantalla de respuesta en Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Estoy intentando hacer un *Hola mundo* en código pascal, en el lazarus. Me compila bien, pero no me aparece la pantalla de respuesta. ¿Qué puede ser?

Aquí les dejo el código.

```pascal
Program HolaMundo;
 begin
    writeln ('Hola mundo.');
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Al revisar la edición a tu pregunta, fijate cómo le di formato de código: agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código.

Comment: [¿Es este tu caso?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60271218)

Comment: Si pruebas tu programa aquí (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler), con el código tal como lo has puesto arriba funciona correctamente. Yo te diría que des más información sobre tu problema.

Imagen:  https://i.imgur.com/wXeCiVm.png